# Vim Fugitive: Gblame reblame options

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive, git-blame

I've been using Fugitive's Gblame recently but don't quite understand what "reblame" does.

Can someone describe a little more clearly what these options do:

```
 -     reblame at commit
 ~     reblame at [count]th first grandparent
 P     reblame at [count]th parent (like HEAD^[count])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think of reblame as navigating to a commit and then running blame on your file or `git blame <commit> -- <file>`

- `-` the simplest case. Use the commit in question under your cursor and reblame the file.
- `~` Is equivalent to running  `git blame <rev>~[count] -- <file>`
- `P` Is equivalent to running  `git blame <rev>^[count] -- <file>`

For the common case, i.e. no `[count]`, `~` and `P` are the equivalent. (Note that `[count]` defaults to 1)

Quick revision tutorial taken from `git help gitrevisions`:

```
Here is an illustration, by Jon Loeliger.
Both commit nodes B and C are parents of commit node A.
Parent commits are ordered left-to-right.

G   H   I   J
 \ /     \ /
  D   E   F
   \  |  / \
    \ | /   |
     \|/    |
      B     C
       \   /
        \ /
         A
A =      = A^0
B = A^   = A^1     = A~1
C = A^2  = A^2
D = A^^  = A^1^1   = A~2
E = B^2  = A^^2
F = B^3  = A^^3
G = A^^^ = A^1^1^1 = A~3
H = D^2  = B^^2    = A^^^2  = A~2^2
I = F^   = B^3^    = A^^3^
J = F^2  = B^3^2   = A^^3^2
```

To understand more about git revision notation see:

- [`git help gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)
- [Git Tools - Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)
- [Carats and Tildes, Resets and Reverts](https://gist.github.com/esmooov/2789156) Note: this article is talking about reset however the graph and revision part is helpful towards the middle of the article.

For more help with `git blame` see `git help blame`

Comment: Thanks, this line helped clear it up for me: "Think of reblame as navigating to a commit and then running blame on your file"