# How to find the first occurrence of a line (or part of a line) using Git?

Tags: git

Let's say we see a line in our code:

```
a = foo.bar + xyz.abc + fn() * 3;
```

now we know `foo.bar` is the "buggy" code or the code causing some issue.  And `git blame` will show that the line is by Michael.  However, Michael might *not* have checked in that part of the code.  He might have only altered the `* 3` part.  So in this case, how could we find the first occurrence of the `foo.bar` in the repo, and find out who wrote it or added that in?

I thought of using

```
git show HEAD:path/to/file.js | grep 'foo.bar'
```

and then

```
git show HEAD~1:path/to/file.js | grep 'foo.bar'
git show HEAD~2:path/to/file.js | grep 'foo.bar'
```

and just increase the `2` to `3`, `4`, etc, until I don't see that line showing the `foo.bar`.

But what if the number can be big, like `120` or `343`.  Is there a better way or faster way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a Git commit that introduced a string in any branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/finding-a-git-commit-that-introduced-a-string-in-any-branch)

Comment: use pickaxe Possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-a-string

Answer (score 1):

You can use blame with commit sha to continue blaming deeper, for example:

```
git blame -L65,+2 -- application.py
# the commit sha in the output is 4dd5a167
# 4dd5a167 (Boris Serebrov 2015-09-08 21:33:20 +0300 65)     except database.ItemNotFound:
# 74311d17 (Boris Serebrov 2015-11-12 11:16:50 +0200 66)         # no node - log error and create it

# continue blaming from the 4dd5a167's parent (4dd5a167^)
git blame -L65,+2 4dd5a167^ -- application.py
```

This feature is used in the [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) vim plugin and it is often very useful. You can do `:Gblame` and then press `~` to "re-blame" the change.
Even if you are not a vim user, it is worth trying to see how it works.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286726/vim-fugitive-gblame-reblame-options) is a good explanation about what fugitive does.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do can be done with the command git-log with the option --grep-reflog.

Since you already know the file you're interested in, I guess the list will be short. With some options well used, I guess all you want can be done with git-log.

[git-log Documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)